# AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'self' error using ChromeOptions for headless Google Chromethrough Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

So I've been trying to get headless chrome working for days. I have no idea whats wrong !! I've tried everything I can find in the forums relating to the issue.

Right now this is the code im running (it's a direct snippet from someone else's tutorial which works fine for them):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


browser_name = "chrome"
if browser_name == 'chrome':
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"./chromedriver", options=options)
    start_url = "https://google.com"
    driver.get(start_url)
    print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
    driver.quit()
```

When I run that code I receive the following error

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"./chromedriver", options=options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 64, in __init__
    desired_capabilities = options.self.to_capabilities()
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'self'
```

It might be worth knowing that the chromedriver is in the correct path, I know this because when I run:

```
 browser_name = "chrome"

 if browser_name == 'chrome':
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./chromedriver")
    start_url = "https://google.com"
    driver.get(start_url)
    print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
    driver.quit()
```

This works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two distinct approaches. If you are using:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

Using only:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

is sufficient.

---

But if you are using the following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

You have to use an instance of `Options()` to set the `headless` property as **`True`** as follows:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"./chromedriver", options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks Debanjan. This might have helped, however I did solve the issue ! I factory reset my computer and now the same code I posed above works fine. I opted for the nuclear approach lol

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when opening browser with Robot-Framework [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser):

```
robot.errors.HandlerExecutionFailed: AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute ''
```

Apparently the `options` argument, which is a string separated with `;` should not end with a `;` such as:

> add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors");add_argument("window-size=1920,1024");add_argument('--no-sandbox');add_argument('--disable-gpu');add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage');

Once I removed the last `;` then the browser was launched with the required options.